# How to use ExposeBeanNameAdvisors`

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I have a requirement to find the name of a bean that I have proxied. Here is some background:

I have the following xml configuration that uses a BeanNameAutoProxyCreator that proxies different beans based on their name (using the NameMatchMethodPointcutAdvisor):

```
<bean id="myAdvisor" class="some.package.MyAdvisor"/>
  <bean id="myProxy"
      class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator"
      p:proxyTargetClass="true">
    <property name="beanNames">
        <list>
            <value>*someBean</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>someInterceptor</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="someInterceptor"
      class="org.springframework.aop.support.NameMatchMethodPointcutAdvisor">
    <property name="mappedName" value="methodName"/>
    <property name="advice" ref="myAdvisor"/>
</bean>
```

Here is the implementation of my advisor. I want to be able to get the name of the bean in this advisor.

```
public class MyAdvisor implements MethodInterceptor {
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {
      // I want to be able to get the bean name of this method invocation here

      try {
          long startTime = System.nanoTime();
          log(startTime);

          return methodInvocation.proceed();
      }
      finally {
          long endTime = System.nanoTime();
          log(endTime);
      }
    }

}
```

I understand that there is a ExposeBeanNameAdvisors class that provides a convenient `getBeanName(MethodInvocation mi)` method I can use. However, I do not understand what is meant by "Assumes that an ExposeBeanNameAdvisor has been included in the interceptor chain." (from javadoc) Can you guys give me an example of how to use ExposeBeanNameAdvisors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ExposeBeanNameAdvisors` has two `static` methods `createAdvisorWithoutIntroduction` and `createAdvisorIntroducingNamedBean` which return an `Advisor` object which should be added to your stack of advisors.

If you look at the implementation of one of these

```
private static class ExposeBeanNameInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

    private final String beanName;

    public ExposeBeanNameInterceptor(String beanName) {
        this.beanName = beanName;
    }

    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation mi) throws Throwable {
        if (!(mi instanceof ProxyMethodInvocation)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("MethodInvocation is not a Spring ProxyMethodInvocation: " + mi);
        }
        ProxyMethodInvocation pmi = (ProxyMethodInvocation) mi;
        pmi.setUserAttribute(BEAN_NAME_ATTRIBUTE, this.beanName);
        return mi.proceed();
    }
}
```

you notice that the bean name is added as an attribute to the `MethodInvocation`, which is cast to a `ProxyMethodInvocation`. This needs to be in the proxy invocation stack before your custom advisor so that you can retrieve the bean name with `ExposeBeanNameAdvisors.getBeanName()`, otherwise you would get an Exception.